# GraphQL subscriptions on Azure Functions - is this possible?

Tags: typescript, graphql, azure-functions

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to get graphql subscriptions to work on azure functions, it looks like apollo-server-azure-functions does not work. Any alternatives or techniques to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

apollo-server-azure-functions does work on Az Function programming model v3 through [this library](https://github.com/apollo-server-integrations/apollo-server-integration-azure-functions).

I opened [this PR](https://github.com/apollo-server-integrations/apollo-server-integration-azure-functions/pull/66) to make Apollo server support the new v4 programming model, but it basically got ignored by the maintainers.

Note: [Do not confuse Runtime version with Programming model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-node-upgrade-v4?tabs=v4#considerations). Azure Function Runtime v4 (the latest) is supported by the apollo graphql server.